# Control MediaPlayer volume with progressbar

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got 2 mediaplayer playing different sounds. I want to use ProgressBar to control MediaPlayer sound. [image]

I know how to control system sound with progress bar but it sets both mediaplayers volume to same, this is what i want:

- If progress bar value is 50 then set MediaPlayer1 and MediaPlayer2 volume to 50
- If progress bar value is 25 then set MediaPlayer1 volume to 75 and MediaPlayer2 volume to 25
- If progress bar value is 0 then set MediaPlayer1 volume to 100 and MediaPlayer2 volume to 0
- If progress bar value is 75 then set MediaPlayer1 volume to 25 and MediaPlayer2 volume to 75
- If progress bar value is 100 then set MediaPlayer1 volume to 0 and MediaPlayer2 volume to 100

Answer (score 1):

Volumecontrol class.

```
public class VolumeControl {
        private static VolumeControl sharedVolumeControl = null;

    /**
     * Obtain the singleton {@link VolumeControl} object.
     * 
     * @return the singleton {@link VolumeControl} object
     */
    public static synchronized VolumeControl sharedVolumeControl() {
        if (sharedVolumeControl == null) {
            sharedVolumeControl = new VolumeControl();
        }

        return sharedVolumeControl;
    }

    /**
     * The {@code VolumeChangeIndicator} enumerates the volume level change
     * indicators that can be used when programmatically changing the volume
     * level (using {@link VolumeControl#setVolume(float)}).
     * 
     * @author Ephraim A. Tekle
     * 
     */
    public static enum VolumeChangeIndicator {
        /**
         * Play a sound when changing the volume
         * 
         * @see #SHOW_DIALOG
         */
        PLAY_SOUND,
        /**
         * Show a (progress bar) dialog when changing the volume
         * 
         * @see #PLAY_SOUND
         */
        SHOW_DIALOG,
        /**
         * Play a sound and show a dialog when changing the volume
         * 
         * @see #PLAY_SOUND
         * @see #SHOW_DIALOG
         */
        PLAY_SOUND_AND_SHOW_DIALOG,
        /**
         * Do not show any volume level change indicator
         */
        NONE;

        int getFlag() {
            switch (this) {
            case PLAY_SOUND:
                return AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND;
            case SHOW_DIALOG:
                return AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI;
            case PLAY_SOUND_AND_SHOW_DIALOG:
                return PLAY_SOUND.getFlag() | SHOW_DIALOG.getFlag();
            default:
                return AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE;
            }
        }
    }

    private VolumeChangeIndicator volumeChangeIndicator = VolumeChangeIndicator.SHOW_DIALOG;
    private final static float GRANULARITY = 100;
    static final int VOLUME_MONITOR_RATE_MS = 1000;
    // static final int VOLUME_MONITOR_RATE_HIGH_MS = 100; // sampling rate when
    // volume change is detected

    private static float SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME;

    private float playerVolume = 1;

    private AudioManager audioManager = null;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private Activity activity = null;

    private boolean inLowVolumeMode = false;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final List<VolumeChangeListener> volumeChangeListeners = new ArrayList<VolumeChangeListener>();
    private volatile float monitoredVolume;
    private volatile boolean stopVolumeMonitor;

    private VolumeControl() {
    }

    /**
     * Configures the {@link VolumeControl} object with the Audio Service system
     * service and {@link AudioManager}.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            the Activity that will be used to retrieve the
     *            {@link AudioManager} and execute listener call backs on the
     *            main thread
     * @param mediaPlayer
     *            the {@link MediaPlayer} being used to play audio/video. While
     *            the {@code VolumeControl} will adjust system volumes, it's
     *            excepted that this class is being used within the context of a
     *            MediaPlayer.
     * @return returns {@code true} if configuration is successful. Returns
     *         {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean configure(Activity activity, MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        if (activity == null || mediaPlayer == null) {
            return false;
        }

        this.audioManager = (AudioManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
        this.activity = activity;

        SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME = audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the {@code VolumeControl} is configured properly.
     * Otherwise, {@code false} is returned.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if this {@code VolumeControl} is configured properly
     *         and can be used.
     */
    public boolean isConfigured() {
        return (this.audioManager != null && this.mediaPlayer != null && this.activity != null);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the volume using {@code AudioManager} and the {@code MediaPlayer}
     * (use {@link #setVolumeChangeIndicator(VolumeChangeIndicator)} to change
     * the volume change indicator).
     * 
     * @param volume
     *            the volume level between 0 (mute) and 1 (maximum volume).
     * @see #setVolumeChangeIndicator(VolumeChangeIndicator)
     */
    public void setVolume(float volume) {

        this.audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) (Math.ceil(SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME * volume)),
                volumeChangeIndicator.getFlag());

        float systemVolume = this.getSystemVolume();

        if (Math.abs(systemVolume - volume) * GRANULARITY >= 1) {

            this.playerVolume = volume / systemVolume;

            this.mediaPlayer.setVolume(this.playerVolume, this.playerVolume);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the current volume level (using {@code AudioManager} and the
     * {@code MediaPlayer})
     * 
     * @return the volume level
     */
    public float getVolume() {
        return this.getSystemVolume() * this.playerVolume;
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to enter a low-volume mode. This is intended to be used
     * when volume {@link AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK} is
     * detected.
     */
    public synchronized void enterLowVolumeMode() {
        if (this.playerVolume > 0.1f) {
            this.mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            this.inLowVolumeMode = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to exit a low-volume mode and set volume to pre
     * audio-focus loss. This is intended to be used when volume
     * {@link AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN} is detected.
     */
    public synchronized void exitLowVolumeMode() {
        if (this.inLowVolumeMode) {
            this.mediaPlayer.setVolume(this.playerVolume, this.playerVolume);
            this.inLowVolumeMode = false;
        }
    }

    private float getSystemVolume() {
        return this.audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                / SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a volume change listener. The listener's {@code VolumeChanged}
     * method is called immediately on the UI thread.
     * 
     * @param l
     *            the {@link VolumeChangeListener} to be added
     */
    public synchronized void addVolumeChangeListener(
            final VolumeChangeListener l) {
        this.volumeChangeListeners.add(l);

        this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                l.volumeChanged(getVolume());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Removes a volume change listener
     * 
     * @param l
     *            the volume change listener to remove
     */
    public synchronized void removeVolumeChangeListener(VolumeChangeListener l) {
        this.volumeChangeListeners.remove(l);
    }

    /**
     * Removes all volume change listeners. This method can be used as a cleanup
     * when the main Activity exits.
     */
    public void removeAllVolumeChangeListeners() {
        this.volumeChangeListeners.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Starts the volume monitor so that {@link VolumeChangeListener}s will get
     * notification if the volume is changed (for example, by the user using the
     * volume up/down buttons).
     */
    public void startVolumeMonitor() {
        stopVolumeMonitor = false;
        this.monitoredVolume = this.getVolume();
        this.primaryVolumeUpdater();
    }

    /**
     * Stops volume monitoring so that no volume change updates are sent to
     * listeners.
     */
    public void stopVolumeMonitor() {
        stopVolumeMonitor = true;
    }

    private void notifyVolumeListenersOnMainThread(final float volume) {
        this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (VolumeChangeListener l : VolumeControl.this.volumeChangeListeners) {
                    l.volumeChanged(volume);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void primaryVolumeUpdater() {
        if (this.stopVolumeMonitor) {
            return;
        }

        float volumeNow = this.getVolume();
        int samplingRate = VOLUME_MONITOR_RATE_MS;

        if (Math.abs(volumeNow - this.monitoredVolume) * GRANULARITY >= 1) {
            this.notifyVolumeListenersOnMainThread(volumeNow);
            // samplingRate = VOLUME_MONITOR_RATE_HIGH_MS;
            // sampling rate made no difference since we are bound by the UI
            // Thread
        }

        this.monitoredVolume = volumeNow;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                primaryVolumeUpdater();
            }
        }, samplingRate);
    }

    /**
     * Set the volume change indicator used when volume is changed using
     * {@link #setVolume(float)}.
     * 
     * @param indicator
     *            the desired volume change indicator
     * @see #getVolumeChangeIndicator()
     */
    public void setVolumeChangeIndicator(VolumeChangeIndicator indicator) {
        this.volumeChangeIndicator = indicator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the volume change indicator used when volume is changed using
     * {@link #setVolume(float)}.
     * 
     * @return the volume change indicator
     * @see #setVolumeChangeIndicator(VolumeChangeIndicator)
     */
    public VolumeChangeIndicator getVolumeChangeIndicator() {
        return this.volumeChangeIndicator;
    }

    /**
     * Interface for receiving notification when the system volume has changed
     * (eg when user changes volume using the device volume buttons). Update
     * calls are done on the UI (i.e. main) thread and therefore are safe to
     * update UI elements within the interface method implementation.
     * 
     * @author Ephraim A. Tekle
     * 
     */
    public static interface VolumeChangeListener {
        public void volumeChanged(float volume);
    }
}
```

implement VolumeChangeListener in your activity.
put value as your progress change

```
VolumeControl.sharedVolumeControl().setVolume(value of progress change);
VolumeControl.sharedVolumeControl().addVolumeChangeListener(this);
        VolumeControl.sharedVolumeControl().startVolumeMonitor(); // this needed
```